# Run a command without PTY

Tags: linux, memory, watch, pty

I am writing a test script and need to gather "free -m" output at some interval at background. However, `watch cmd` sends control sequences to delete old output, thinking it is in a terminal. But I don't want that, I want the values throught the process. Is this possible?

In short; I run

`watch -n 1 "free -m | grep buffers/cache" > time`

And I expect time to have multiple lines of:

`-/+ buffers/cache:       2212       5730
-/+ buffers/cache:       2219       5730
-/+ buffers/cache:       2217       5730`

However it only contains:

`0u May  8 20:39:19 2014
-/+ buffers/cache:       2212       5730`

Comment: Please re-title your question to state what you actually wanted to do, rather than a solution that you didn't need and isn't given in the answers. (I actually need to run a command without a PTY to test a script that's expected to run without one, and this question comes up at the top of the search list but doesn't help at all.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a loop:

```
while : ; do free -m | grep buffers; sleep 1; done
```

The colon is equivalent to `true`.

Redirect to a file called `time` if you like:

```
while : ; do free -m | grep buffers >> time; sleep 1; done
```